# JQuery form validition code and preventdefault aren't not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a bootstrap signup form and the following jQuery code is not working. Despite the `e.preventDefault()` , the form is still being submitted, and the `div` containing the error message does not appear either.

Also, I have a login form with pretty much the exact same code and that one is working properly

```js
$(function(){
  
$("#signup-form").on("submit",function(e){
  
var email=$("#emal");
var name=$("#username");
var ps=$("#password");
var psr=$("#passwordrepeat");
var error=$("#errormessage");
var errorcontainer=$("#errordiv");

if(name.val()=="" && ps.val()=="" && email.val()=="" && psr.val()==""){
 error.text("Fields are empty!");
 errorcontainer.removeClass("d-none");
 errorcontainer.addClass("errorbg");
 name.addClass("error");
 ps.addClass("error");
 email.addClass("error");
 psr.addClass("error");
 e.preventDefault();
}


});
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#9ec3ff !important;
 }

 .container{
  background:#9ec3ff;
 }
 
 .col-lg-6{
  margin:auto;
 }
 
 #facebook{
  background:#568ac2 !important;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px !important;
 }
 #twitter{
  background:#6aabdb;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px !important;
 }
 #google{
  background:#cb3d2f;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px !important;
 }
 #signupform{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #2e51a2;
 }
 #signupform:hover{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 50px #2e51a2;
  transition:0.5s;
 }
  .error{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #cb3d2f;
 }
 .errorbg{
  border:2px solid red;
  background:#fae3e3;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/' crossorigin='anonymous'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  
<div id="errordiv" class="m-auto text-danger font-weight-bold text-center col-lg-6 col-md-8 d-none">
  
  <span id="errormessage"></span>

</div>

<div class="row mt-5">
  <div id="signupform" class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 border border-primary text-center">
    <span class="m-auto"><strong>Sign Up with</strong></span><br><br>
    <div class="m-auto col-xl-10 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" id="facebook" class="btn btn-primary float-left"><img class="mr-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/9FWWsfx.png"/>Facebook</button>
      <button type="button" id="twitter" class="btn btn-primary float-center"><img class="mr-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/LXFDLev.png"/>Twitter</button>
      <button type="button" id="google" class="btn btn-primary float-right"><img class="mr-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/AN3CMg9.png"/>Google+</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <span class="m-auto">Or</span><br>
    <br>
<form id="signup-form">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput"><strong>E-mail</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="signup-email">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="username" placeholder="Choose username" name="signup-username">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="signup-password">
  </fieldset>
 <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Password again</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="passwordrepeat" placeholder="Enter password" name="signup-passwordrepeat">
  </fieldset>
   
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the <a href="#">Term of Service</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </label>
      </div>
    <input type="submit" name="signup" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" value="Create Account"/>
  
</form>

  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `preventdefault` on top of the function.
There are a set of functions which are run in the background when submit is called. In `Javascript` when a function starts running there is no way it could stop. It only stops when it throws an error or if it returns a value. Using `preventdefalut` at the last doesn't help because it is too late and the submit function has began to run. When placed at the top of the `function` it explicitly says that the default submit functions aren't to be run.

```js
$(function(){
  
$("#signup-form").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
var email=$("#emal");
var name=$("#username");
var ps=$("#password");
var psr=$("#passwordrepeat");
var error=$("#errormessage");
var errorcontainer=$("#errordiv");

if(name.val()=="" && ps.val()=="" && email.val()=="" && psr.val()==""){
 error.text("Fields are empty!");
 errorcontainer.removeClass("d-none");
 errorcontainer.addClass("errorbg");
 name.addClass("error");
 ps.addClass("error");
 email.addClass("error");
 psr.addClass("error");
 
}


});
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#9ec3ff !important;
 }

 .container{
  background:#9ec3ff;
 }
 
 .col-lg-6{
  margin:auto;
 }
 
 #facebook{
  background:#568ac2 !important;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px !important;
 }
 #twitter{
  background:#6aabdb;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px !important;
 }
 #google{
  background:#cb3d2f;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px !important;
 }
 #signupform{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #2e51a2;
 }
 #signupform:hover{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 50px #2e51a2;
  transition:0.5s;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/' crossorigin='anonymous'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  
<div id="errordiv" class="m-auto text-danger font-weight-bold text-center col-lg-6 col-md-8 d-none">
  
  <span id="errormessage"></span>

</div>

<div class="row mt-5">
  <div id="signupform" class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 border border-primary text-center">
    <span class="m-auto"><strong>Sign Up with</strong></span><br><br>
    <div class="m-auto col-xl-10 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" id="facebook" class="btn btn-primary float-left"><img class="mr-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/9FWWsfx.png"/>Facebook</button>
      <button type="button" id="twitter" class="btn btn-primary float-center"><img class="mr-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/LXFDLev.png"/>Twitter</button>
      <button type="button" id="google" class="btn btn-primary float-right"><img class="mr-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/AN3CMg9.png"/>Google+</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <span class="m-auto">Or</span><br>
    <br>
<form id="signup-form">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput"><strong>E-mail</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="signup-email">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="username" placeholder="Choose username" name="signup-username">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="signup-password">
  </fieldset>
 <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Password again</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control w-75 m-auto" id="passwordrepeat" placeholder="Enter password" name="signup-passwordrepeat">
  </fieldset>
   
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the <a href="#">Term of Service</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </label>
      </div>
    <input type="submit" name="signup" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" value="Create Account"/>
  
</form>

  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it said *why* putting it at the top of the function is better than the current placement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `return false;` when validation fails (and `preventDefault` as well)
like following:

```
$(function(){

$("#signup-form").on("submit",function(e){

var email=$("#emal");
var name=$("#username");
var ps=$("#password");
var psr=$("#passwordrepeat");
var error=$("#errormessage");
var errorcontainer=$("#errordiv");

if(name.val()=="" && ps.val()=="" && email.val()=="" && psr.val()==""){
    error.text("Fields are empty!");
    errorcontainer.removeClass("d-none");
    errorcontainer.addClass("errorbg");
    name.addClass("error");
    ps.addClass("error");
    email.addClass("error");
    psr.addClass("error");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; // return false here to disallow from for submitting
}


});
});
```